Wrote a program to print prime numbers, How do I make it better?
I started learning C the previous day and I wrote a program to print within a given range. Minimum and Maximum of range is given by user.
#include <stdio.h>
int check(int number)
{
    if (number == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 2;
    while (count < number)
    {
        if (number%count == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return 1;
}
void main()
{
    int i,min,max;
    printf("Enter start of range: ");
    scanf("%d",&min);
    printf("Enter end of range: ");
    scanf("%d",&max);
    for (i = min;i < max;i++)
    {
        if (check(i) == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
}

I am getting the output as expected, but I want to know if there is any better way to return 0 if the number entered is 1 or not as it appears like duct tape code to me.
I inserted this block of code before the program goes through a while loop to check for numbers>1.
if (number == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

I am getting the output as expected but I want to know if there is a better way than just placing an if statement.
My question is different from the suggested question because I want to know if there is any better way to figure out if 1 is not a prime number. The suggested question was using an if statement, just like how I did.
If statement was present in suggested question, I wanted to know any other alternatives that does not use the if statement to check for 1.
I find my question different from the suggested question.

What you have written is perfectly fine. It's easy to read and understand, and it's also easy for the compiler to optimize it if needed. The only change I would make is to change the loop in the check function to a for loop.

Except for a better (that is "less generic") function name (maybe is_prime or similar), that function is OK. Your flaws are in main where you should always check the return value of scanf

You could improve the main loop by ensuring that you start with the nearest odd number to min, and increase the lopp conter by two each time. There is no point in checking even numbers since they (apart from 2) cannot be prime. Also in your check method, you only need to count up to (number /2), as all valid divisions will be complete by then.

You only need to test up to sqrt (number)

@pm100 introducing float point numbers into an essentialy integer problem creates more problems than needed.

How to make it better? Always check the return of every input function to verify whether input succeeded or failed.

Probably the biggest improvement in performance would come from special casing the test for divides by 2 with if (!(number & 1)) return 0 and then starting count from 3 and stepping by count += 2 each time. Also change the loop condition to while (count*count < number).  Both of these prevent a lot of unnecessary work. A slightly fancier scheme alternating between increments of 2 and 4 can skip all numbers divisible by three. General heuristic is that divides are about the most expensive operation - almost every other binary operation takes one machine cycle on a modern CPU.

@MartinBrown if (!(number & 1)) return 0 better as if (number % 2 == 0) return 0  for clearer code (and pedantically work with non-2's complement).  if (number % 2 == 0) return number == 2 is even better.  count*count < number overflows for large primes.  count < number/count avoids that and has little cost for a compiler that does / and % together.

You should post this to codereview.stackexchange.com.

@chux The last machine I used that wasn't two's compliment was back in 1984. Are there any modern CPU's that still do sign magnitude (perhaps DSP chips?) or ones complement these days? I grant you that there is a possibility of overflow but it can only happen if number is a Mersenne prime of the form 2^N-1 where N is the machine integer size in bits. So it would I think fail for 32bit ints as 2^31-1 is prime, Otherwise numbers of that form are composite and typically divide by at least one of 3,5,7. Another trivial improvement to the program is to use unsigned int.

@MartinBrown 1) The non-2's complement issue is an aside.  number % 2 == 0 remains clearer than !(number & 1)  2) "possibility of overflow but it can only happen if number is a Mersenne prime" --> divisor * divisor overflows when number == 2147483629 or 2147483549 or other select large primes, even if not a Mersenne prime.

@chux you are right. I hadn't spotted that gotcha.

There is Code Review@SE.

Apologies @greybeard, I did not know that existed

Is it fine if I explicitly convert the square root to an integer and iterate till that integer?

@chux-ReinstateMonica The most efficient optimization would do away with the if altogether (because jumps can be terrible on modern CPUs) and replace it with bit arithmetic, taking advantage of C's weak typing, like return 1 & (number != 1).

[ a little late to the prime party]

How do I make it better?

Fix prime check
check(0) reports true.  check(any_negative) reports true.  Both should report false.
Much too slow
check(n) iterates up to n times.  A simple change would iterate at most sqrt(n) times.  That is 10,000 times faster for large n.
Iterate while the divisor is less than or equal to the quotient.
int prime_check(int number) {
  if (number % 2 == 0) {
    return number == 2;
  }
  // Do not use divisor*divisor <= number as that overflows for a large prime.
  // Good compilers emit efficient code for number / divisor and
  // nearby number % divisor, doing both for the time cost of one.
  for (int divisor = 3; divisor <= number / divisor; divisor += 2) {
    if (number % divisor == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return number > 1;
}

Questionable max
I'd expect max to be part of the range that is tested.
  printf("Enter end of range: ");
  scanf("%d",&max);
  // for (i = min; i < max; i++)
  for (i = min; i <= max; i++)

Yet this is a problem when max == INT_MAX.

I think I'll fix that by accepting only integers below INT_MAX, thank you.

More useful if you want to become a c programmer ... What happens if I enter "frog" as the min value . Now you enter the world of error detection and recovery

A little circuitous, but I accept this as an answer to "How to make this code better?". ;-)

"circumloquacious" perhaps for "check every input return or risk UB" :)

"What happens if I enter "frog" as the min"  The program counter will jump non-conditionally to the nearest memory pool.

I did not think of that, thank you.

Checking the return from input functions is important. Also possibly addressed by initializing variables like min and max when declaring them, rather than counting on scanf to do it.

@Chris and learn how to rest the stdin buffer and how to loop nicely reprompting the user

This is one of the issues all starting programmers deal with: how to you check if a number is prime, and generally the thinking goes as follows:

Make a counter, starting by 2 and go up to the number itself and check using the modulo function.
Realize that because you have already checked for oddness by dividing by 2, you only need to test odd divisors after that.
You realize that because products are pairs, you redundantly check every pair twice if you test all divisors up to the number itself. The symmetry inflection point of the factor pairs is the square root of the number, so that's your divisor limit.
You wonder how expensive it is to compute that and perform benchmarks to find the limit beyond which it makes sense to use the square root instead of, say, simply testing up to n/2.
You wonder whether you should download and incorporate into your program the first, say, million or billion prime numbers to provide near-instantaneous answers for numbers up to that limit and improve answer speeds for numbers up to 1014 or 1020 because it is actually only necessary to divide by prime numbers. You realize that you may need special provisions to represent numbers larger than 232 (~4.2*109), and usually larger than 264 (~1.8*1019).


Also only check modulo against odd numbers, except for 2.

@Fredrik: feel free to modify my answer, it might become a reference for this type of question :-)

You don't really need to calculate the square root... just go up until the number you're checking multiplied by itself is greater than the limit.

I thik this does not actually answer the question as asked, which puts the focus on " want to know if there is any better way to return 0 if the number entered is 1 or not as it appears like duct tape code to me." I think OPs code does match accepted definition, your steps don't. On top of that I am unsatisfied with the precision of the last steps phrasing, which can be read so that corresponding code has an off-by-one error.

@pmg "go up until the number you're checking multiplied by itself is greater than the limit." has a short-coming.  It overflows when limit is a large prime.

Right @chux, thanks. OP I revise my comment to "go up until n > limit / n"

Is checking for quotient faster than iterating till the square root?

I accepted your invitation to edit. Feel free to roll back or modify if unhappy.

Your program works as expected for valid input, which is a good start. Here are ways to improve the code, especially the check function as requested:

use the correct prototype for main without arguments: int main(void).
check for valid input: scanf() returns 1 is an integer was entered, otherwise you must handle the error explicitly.
use a more explanatory name for the check function such as isprime.
it is idiomatic in C for boolean functions to return 0 for false and non zero for true.  Just testing if (isprime(i)) is more readable.
check for more values to reject: if (n < 2) instead of if (n == 1). If you cannot assume that the argument n is at least 2, you need to use a test like this to reject lower values.  With a different loop, you could try and avoid this test, but it is not worth the effort: this test is simple and readable and will cost almost nothing if most values are valid.
testing for division remainders should stop as soon as the quotient is smaller than the divisor.
testing 2 explicitly before the loop and only testing odd divisors  in the loop would further improve performance.
to compute prime numbers in a range, trial division is less efficient than the ancient Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Here is a modified version:

 #include <stdio.h>
 
int isprime(int number)
{
    if (number < 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        return number == 2;
    }
    for (int divisor = 3;; divisor += 2) {
        // optimizing compilers will likely compute both the
        // quotient and remainder with a single instruction
        int quotient = number / divisor;
        int remainder = number % divisor;
        if (quotient < divisor)
            return 1;
        if (remainder == 0)
            return 0;
    }
}
 
int main(void)
{
    int i, min, max;
 
    printf("Enter start of range: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &min) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter end of range: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &max) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
        if (isprime(i)) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


How is 'void main()' different from 'int main(void)'?

Is using an if statement the only way to check exclude numbers below 2?

@nkminion "Is using an if statement the only way to check ..." --> No.  Alternative: return a compare.

It's a minor thing, but probably print those "invalid input\n" messages to stderr rather than stdout.

@nkminion: technically you could write while (number < 2) { return 0; } instead of while (number < 2) { return 0; }. The compiler should generate the same code, but readers of your code will ponder why you did not use if...

@Chris: yes of course, maybe beyond the OP's skill level after just one day of C, but it cannot hurt to learn this quickly.

@chqrlie thank you for the while loop suggestion.

Besides checking if every number in range is prime there are other approaches to consider:
Sieve of Eratosthenes
Is an algorithm to generate all prime numbers between 1 and N.
Its time complexity is O(max log log max) making it way faster. However it has disadvantages for big numbers such as high space requirements and cache thrashing. There are variations on the algorithm that address these problems like Segmented sieve and Incremental sieve.
Precomputed array
For a 32 bit integer there are 105'097'565 positive prime numbers. You can write a program to generate them or you can find on the internet archive files with them and use that. Then you put them in your program (e.g. in a file that your program reads).
You can store them as an ordered array of integers then you find the position of the first prime number in your range in O(log n) with binary search (it's actually O(1) because n is a constant 105'097'565). Then you just walk and print the array until you get a number bigger than your max.

Difficulty considerations
If you just started C these options might be too much for you at this stage.
However it's good to be aware of them, even if you don't understand half of what you are reading. Then, after you learn and practice more, you can revisit them and attempt to implement them. And be proud of how far you've progressed 

There are several ways to improve the prime detection algorithm itself. It has been answered thoroughly before, e.g. here, so I will not go further into that.
Next, is the question of how to validate the input. The scanf() returns the number of successfully converted values, so that must be checked to ensure the user entered a valid integer. Also, it should be checked if the values are within an allowed range. The check() function assumes that the argument is a positive integer, so either it must be made robust to a non-positive integer or it must be ensured that it will only be called with a positive integer.
Specifically, the check could be changed to:
    if (number <= 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

However, it may be better to inform the user in case the input seems wrong. All in all, the main() function could be written as follows:
int main()
{
    int i,min,max;
    printf("Enter start of range: ");
    if(scanf("%d",&min) != 1)
    {
       printf("Input must be an integer\n");
       return 0;
    }
    if(min < 1)
    {
       printf("Input must be a positive integer\n");
       return 0;
    }
    printf("Enter end of range: ");
    if(scanf("%d",&max) != 1)
    {
       printf("Input must be an integer\n");
       return 0;
    }
    if(max < min)
    {
       printf("Range is empty\n");
       return 0;
    }
    for (i = min;i <= max;i++)
    {
        if (check(i) == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
}

Note: In the for-loop, I changed the end condition to i <= max since a user is likely to expect the end of the range to be included in the checked values.
As this example shows, it is often easy to make a program which works when everything goes well. Making a program which is reasonably robust to all exceptions is significantly more difficult.

Some years ago I took this from a book, maybe "Algorithms in C", which uses sqrt() and floor() to look at when to break the loop, with a few small additions of my own:
/* return 1 if n is a prime number  */
int is_prime(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int spia,f;
    if ( !n ) return 0;
    if ( n <= 3 ) return 1;
    if ( (n % 2) && (n % 3) ) {
      spia = (unsigned int) floor(sqrt(n));
      for ( f=5 ; (n % f) && (n % (f+2)) && f <= spia ; f+=6 ) ;
      if ( f > spia ) return 1;
    } // endif
    return 0;
}

Based on previous answers I checked this version with sqrt() removed and replaced by / (integer division) to look at when to break the loop:
int is_prime_w_div(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int f;
    if ( !n ) return 0;
    if ( n <= 3 ) return 1;
    if ( (n % 2) && (n % 3) ) {
      for ( f=5 ; (n % f) && (n % (f+2)) ; f+=6 ) {
            if ( f > n/f ) break;
      } // endfor
      if ( f > n/f ) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

I timed both version over 10 million integers ( from 0 to 10000000 ) both on a Raspi400 running Raspbian Linux and on a Geekom Mini IT13 Core i9-13900H running OpenSuse Leap15.6 and in both cases the sqrt() version was the fastest:
/* testprime.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* put is_prime and is_prime_w_div here */

int main(void) {
  unsigned int i,cnt;
  for ( cnt=0,i=0 ; i<10000000 ; i++) {
    if (is_prime(i)) cnt++;
    /* if (is_prime_w_div(i)) cnt++; */
  } /* endif */
  printf("found %u primes\n",cnt);
  return 0;
}

/*
 * gcc testprime.c -lm
 * time ./a.out
 */ 

So what the story? On modern hardware floating point math is in hardware, and sqrt() is NOT called in loop on each iteration.
Or I'm missing something else?

I wanted to see whether it is possible to compute the primes at compile time with constexpr and give virtually instantaneous answers at run time.
I found a solution for "compile time loops" with some template magic here and modified it for this purpose. It works indeed, but compiler and other tool limits restrict the maximum number to check because the template magic unrolls the loops recursively — nested recursively in the case of pre-computing an entire list.
One obvious optimization would be to use the computed primes so far as divisors, instead of all numbers. Also, for numbers larger than CHECK_LIMIT but smaller than its square, one could use the prime numbers as divisors and be faster than a naive computation.—
Both g++ and Visual C++ need special options already for primes up to 200 (for g++ -Wa,-mbig-obj and later also e.g. -ftemplate-depth=5000, for Visual C++ /bigobj).
Compile times are quite long (40 seconds with g++), but the run time is "instantaneous". The executable is quite big, 13 MB with gcc and 4 MB with Visual C++.
I hope it is valuable as a proof of concept:
// Prime number compile time demo.
// Uses ideas from https://artificial-mind.net/blog/2020/10/31/constexpr-for
// 
// Needs C++20 for set::contains convenience

#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template<long long NUM, long long DIVISOR>
constexpr bool isDivisible()
{
    return NUM % DIVISOR == 0;
}

/// <summary>
///  Template magic that recursively unrolls a for loop
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="F">
/// The type of something to be called on each incremented loop value</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="Start"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="End"></typeparam>
/// <param name="f">What to call for each loop variable value</param>
template <auto Start, auto End, class F>
constexpr void constexpr_for(F&& f)
{
    if constexpr (Start < End)
    {
        f(std::integral_constant<decltype(Start), Start>());
        constexpr_for<Start + 1, End>(f);
    }
}

/// <summary>Divide NUM by each number up to NUM/2 and
/// <return> 0 if any division has no remainder.
template <int NUM>
bool isPrime()
{
    bool res = true;
    constexpr_for<2, NUM/2+1>([&res](auto i) {
        res &= !isDivisible<NUM, i>();
        });
    return res;
}

/// <summary>
/// Fill a set with prime numbers up to the limit End-1
/// </summary>
template <int End>
std::set<int> makePrimes()
{
    std::set<int> primes;
    constexpr_for<2, End>([&primes](auto i) {
        if (isPrime<i>()) primes.emplace(i);
        });
    return primes;
}

int main()
{
    // direct test, precomputed
    std::cout << "97 is prime: " << isPrime<97>() << "\n\n";

    // pre-compute during compilation (takes a few minutes with gcc,
    // needs -Wa,-mbig-obj)
    const int CHECK_LIMIT = 200;
    std::set<int> primes = makePrimes<CHECK_LIMIT>();
    for (int i = 0; i< CHECK_LIMIT; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << (primes.contains(i) ? " is prime" : "") << "\n";
    }
}


I share with you another approach to achieve your objective.
First Note: to avoid "number 1" check at each check function call, move the if control outside that function and outside you for cycle. In this way you will be able to perform this check once time.
Second Note: use recursive function to create iterative check on each number you want to analyse.
The check function become:
int check(int counter, int number)
{
    
    if(number%counter){
        //mod result is not zero
        //increase counter
        counter++;

        //if counter is equal to number
        //it means that number is prime - return 1 to caller!
        //otherwise call check function again with new counter value
        if(counter==number)
            return 1;
        else
            if(check(counter, number))
                //check returns 1 - number is prime! return 1 to caller
                return 1;  
            else
                //check returns 0 - number is not prime! return 0 to caller
                return 0;
    }else{
        //number is not prime
        //return 0 to caller
        return 0;
    }

}

using recursive call you can perform iterative checks without using cycle
Here my complete code with comments:
#include <stdio.h>

//declare functions
int check(int counter, int number);

int main()
{
    int i,min,max;
    printf("Enter start of range: ");
    scanf("%d",&min);
    printf("Enter end of range: ");
    scanf("%d",&max);
    
    // if first number is 1, i'll skip it
    if(min == 1){
        min++;
    }

    if(min == 2){
        //2 is prime, print it and increment min
        printf("%d\n",min++);
       
    }

    for (i = min;i <= max;i++)
    {
   
        
        //call recursive function for checking prime
        if (check(2,i))
            printf("%d\n",i);
        

    }
    return 0;
}


/*check function is recursive.
*  it acceptes counter and number values
*  perform prime check:
*    - it's prime number - recursive function stack will be close and return 1
*    - it's not prime number - counter will be increased and check function will be called again from itself
*/  
int check(int counter, int number)
{

    if(number%counter){
        //mod result is not zero
        //increase counter
        counter++;

        //if counter is equal to number
        //it means that number is prime - return 1 to caller!
        //otherwise call check function again with new counter value
        if(counter==number)
            return 1;
        else
            if(check(counter, number))
                //check returns 1 - number is prime! return 1 to caller
                return 1;  
            else
                //check returns 0 - number is not prime! return 0 to caller
                return 0;
    }else{
        //number is not prime
        //return 0 to caller
        return 0;
    }

}

Pros: cleaned code layout, better quantum time consuming (when you analyse not high prime number)
Cons: little bit more complex, less stack memory use, probably stack overflow problem when you analyse high prime number
Last considerations: for more improvements you should implement controls on inputs (min and max values) to avoid unexpected behaviours
EDIT: I changed my code deleting pointers and moving stack memory use in cons

I'm afraid this approach is highly inefficient and does not handle numbers below 2 correctly: none of these numbers are prime.  Your code prints 1 as a prime number and loops for a long time for 0 and negative numbers before invoking undefined behavior.

using recursive call you can perform iterative checks without using cycle, from quantum time point of view you may save resources and improve efficiency where on earth do they teach this?  Furthermore there is absolutely no need to use pointers and counter++ does not increment the counter, it just increases the pointer, causing undefined behavior on any composite number.  Also less stack memory use is incorrect, more stack use is more likely and it is a con.

“I use pointer instead variable for use less memory in stack in each check function call” - this is entirely incorrect.

I apologize for my wrong code. It contains a lot of mistakes (yes number 1 is not prime but 2 is prime and my code doesn't recognise it). Moreover, in this case, I could implement recursive function without pointers. I got it.

N3tMaster, if number was a large prime, say about 1,000,000,000, I'd expect check() to recurse about 1,000,000,000 times before unwinding and reporting a prime.  Such stack depth will cause stack overflow on many machine.  IMO, recursion, as used here, is not the right approach.

@chux-ReinstateMonica, yes you're right. i'is not the best solution when manipulating large amount of numbers
